# Confidence Interval for Estimator using Delta method

Tags: central-limit-theorem, estimators, method-of-moments, delta-method

**The statement**

I am given the following discrete distribution with $\theta>0$

$$p(x) = \left(\frac{\theta}{1+\theta}\right) ^{2-x}\left(\frac{1}{1+\theta}\right)^{x-1} \hspace{1cm} x=1,2$$

I need to calculate an estimator of $\theta$ (call it $T_n$) using a sample $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$, deduce its distribution and calculate a confidence interval for $\theta$.

**What I did**

If $X_1,...,X_n$ are n copies of $X$, the sample is $x_1=X_1(\omega),..., x_n=X_n(\omega)$

Using the method of moments we can relate the sample mean to the expectation

$$\overline X_n = E[X] = 1+\frac{1}{1+\theta}=\mu$$

and define the estimator of $\theta$

$$T_n=\frac{1}{\overline X_n-1}-1$$

I also calculated the variance of X: $Var(X)=\frac{\theta}{(1+\theta)^2}=\sigma^2$

By the Central Limit Theorem

$$\sqrt{n}\,(\overline X_n-\mu) \rightarrow N(0,\sigma^2)$$

We can apply the Delta Method with the function $g(t)=\frac{1}{t-1}-1$ to get

$$\sqrt{n}\,(g(\overline X_n)-g(\mu)) \rightarrow N(0,\sigma^2g’(\mu)^2)$$

i.e.

$$\sqrt{n}\,(T_n-\theta) \rightarrow N(0,\theta(1+\theta)^2)$$

**My Problem**

Now I need to determine the distribution of $T_n$ but I don’t know the value of $\theta.$ I could approximate $\theta$ by $T_n$ and use Slutsky’s theorem to conclude that

$$\sqrt{n}\,\frac{(T_n-\theta)}{\sqrt{T_n}(T_n+1)} \rightarrow N(0,1)$$

But again I don’t know how to obtain the distribution of $T_n$.

Comment: $T_n$ isn't even a random variable, because it isn't completely defined: what should it equal when $\bar x_n=1$??

Comment: @whuber but if $\theta$ Is greater than 0, $\overline X_n$ Is greater than 1. Should I substitute $\overline x_n$ with $\overline X_n$?

Comment: I don't understand what distinction you are making with that notation.  By definition, the estimator is a function of the sample, which always has a positive chance of consisting entirely of $n$ $1$s.

Comment: @whuber Okay, I think I get it... So how could I solve the problem? Is the approach correct or do I have to think a completely different thing?

Comment: You could consider the MLE of $\theta$ which also has an asymptotic normal distribution.

Comment: The MLE is one solution.  The other is to complete the definition of your estimator by stating what value of $\theta$ should be estimated when $\bar x_n=1.$  That would be a little complicated due to the need to analyze everything conditionally on this event, but it could be done.  There are other solutions, too, because there exist plenty of good estimators of $\theta$ and not all of them need to be MLEs.

Comment: @StubbornAtom with the MLE I get $\hat{\theta}=\frac{S_n - 2n}{n-S_n}$ where $S_n$ is the sum of $x_1...x_n$. However, I think the exercise as stated wants me to use the moments method. How should I continue? Should I apply Delta Method to the MLE?

Comment: @whuber are there other estimators related to the expectation of X that could work? The exercise is phrased in a way that seems to relate the estimator to EX, thats why I thought using the moment method.

Comment: Because $X-1$ is a Bernoulli variable, the sum has a Binomial distribution.  Thus, one route is to find an estimator of $\Pr(X=2)$ (the Bernoulli parameter) and convert that into an estimator of $\theta.$ This also points the way to using logistic regression (which in its usual form computes the MLE of $\log\theta$).

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the help! I’m having some difficulty understanding your approach because this subject I’m taking is on probability theory (we follow Billingsley) and we didn’t do almost any statistics, just Delta Method, and the usual limit theorems. Is there a way to do this with Delta method/CLT and such?